# Assert.IsType() Failure

Tags: xunit

Im not sure why im failing this test.

```
Message: 
Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult
Actual:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult

var controller = GetMockedTokenController();
var response = await controller.Search(GetSearchMasterCardTokenRequestDto(), Id);
var objectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there’s no actual difference between an ObjectResult and an OkObjectResult. An OkObjectResult just return an object result and sets the status code to 200.

You can see that in your error message that the actual responded type is just an ObjectResult